# vector problem in parallelopiped

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to find out  absolute volume the parallelopiped [image]

I have  not got  that how they did with this vector notation,   $h= \vec{A}\cdot \vec{n} $

The volume will be  $\vec{A}\cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{C}) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|\vec{n}|=1$ and $\vec{A}\cdot \vec{n}=|\vec{A}||\vec{n}|cos(\alpha)=|\vec{A}|cos(\alpha)=h$